# Trying to solve an Exercism question, Gigasecond, Javacsript

Tags: javascript, date, ecmascript-6

I am trying to solve a problem:
Given a moment, determine the moment that would be after a gigasecond has passed.
A gigasecond is 10^9 (1,000,000,000) seconds.Do not mutate the function's arguments.

```
   const gigasecond = () => {
     \\write your code here 
   };
```

I wrote a code which I think should solve it, but, I am getting a failed test. My code is:

```
const gigasecond = () => {
let date = new Date();
const gs = Math.pow(10, 12);
let futureTime = date.getTime() + gs;
return new Date(futureTime)
```

};

I am really stuck, and not sure what did I miss.

Comment: Your function always returns the current time plus a "gigasecond". The description of the problem suggests that the function should take a parameter of some kind, either a Date instance or a timestamp (number).

Comment: Correct, the problem is how can I access the expected parameter without an argument or mutating the argument??

Comment: "Do not mutate the function's arguments" means that the function should not change the value(s), it does not mean that you cannot have an argument.

Comment: Ok, I did put an argument, and it passed the first test. I'll submit it and see if it is accepted. Thanks @Pointy foryour response.

Comment: Consider `let plusGs = d => new Date(+d + 1e12)`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG I tried it, but, it did;n work. Thanks for your response and please check my answer below.

Comment: const gigasecond = (time) => {
  let date = time.getTime();
  const gs = Math.pow(10, 12);
  let futureTime = date + gs;

  return new Date(futureTime)
};

Comment: @sumalille—did you call it with a Date? e.g. `plusGs(new Date())`? Works fine. Maybe  set a default: `let plusGs = (d = new Date()) => new Date(+d + 1e12);` so you can call it with or without a Date.

Comment: @RobG It does work, I am sure it is a perfect code, but  it didn't pass the test. It is my fault. I did not post the question correctly. I will edit it.

Comment: I am sorry to @all. This is my first question here ;)

Comment: Ok, so just adapt it to suit: `const gigasecond = (d) => {return  new Date(+d + 1e12)};` though the `{}` and `return` are redundant. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, @RobG. Your code is succinct and perfect. Indeed, it passed the test without the curlies and return! :)

Answer (score 0):

If I add an argument my code will be:

```
const gigasecond = (time) => {
  let date = time.getTime();
  const gs = Math.pow(10, 12);
  let futureTime = date + gs;

  return new Date(futureTime)
};
```

and it did pass the first test. I'll cross fingers and see if it is accepted or not.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is as follow:

```
public static class Gigasecond {
public static DateTime Add(DateTime moment)
   {
       return moment.AddSeconds(Math.Pow(10,9));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Solution is as follows:

```
import datetime
def add(moment):
    return moment+ datetime.timedelta(seconds=10**9)
```